# SQL query for merging timestamps

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7

I have data in postgres table in the following form:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3              Col4
id1    a       b                 c 
id2    id1     timeBegin         1###-##-##
id2    id1     timeEnd           22##-##-##
id3    id4     id5               id6
id6    id3     timeBegin         2##-##-##
id7    id3     timeEnd           200-3-## 
id13   id8     id14              id15
id8    id9     timeBegin         -2-1-1
id10   id11    id12              id13
```

Here 1###-##-## imply an uncertainty in time from (1000-01-01 to 1999-12-31)

and  22##-##-## imply an uncertainty in time from (2200-01-01 to 2200-12-31)

and 2##-##-## imply an uncertainty in time from (200-01-01 to 200-12-31)

and 200-3-## imply an uncertainity in time from (200-3-01 to 200-3-31)

and 20-3-## imply an uncertainty in time from (20-3-01 to 20-3-31)

and 200-3-## imply an uncertainty in time from (200-3-01 to 200-3-31)

and -200-3-## imply an uncertainty in time from (-200-3-31 to -200-3-01)

Now I want to merge 3 rows where col1==col2 into one of the following form:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3              Col4       timeBegin      timeEnd
id1    a       b                 c          1000-01-01     2200-12-31 
id3    id4     id5               id6        200-01-02      200-3-31
id10   id11    id12              id13       NULL           NULL
id13   id8     id14              id15       2-1-1 BC       9999-12-12
```

If timeEnd for col1==col2 is not given the 9999-12-12 is presumed as timeEnd

If timeBegin for col1==col2 is not given then 01-01-01 is presumed as timeBegin

i.e. I want to take minimum of timeBegin and maximum of timeEnd while merging.

Is it possible to do this join operation in postgres. i.e. can I write this as an SQL join query?

If I can achieve what is desired using a programming language like python (in an efficient manner) also: then that will be great.

Comment: How far can the hashes go? can you have `1999-12-1#`? for example?

Comment: If it is PostgreSQL why have you tagged this as SQL Server AND MySQL?

Comment: @Laurence 1999-12-1# implies "1999-12-10 to 1999-12-19"

Comment: @JannatArora So why does `1###-##-##` allow dates up to `2200-12-31`? surely the first 2 doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: @Laurence Actually whenever we have values both for timeBegin and timeEnd, then we merge them together, taking the minimum uncertainty value from timeBegin and maximum uncertainty value from timeEnd.

Comment: @Laurence You are right..i have corrected the mistake..i hope that will help you to help me.

Comment: @JannatArora: The question would have been clearer with the actual column names... Col1 and Col2 seem to be an id and parent_id (integers?). I'm a bit at a loss as to what col3 and col4 actually represent, let alone how they're stored. This sort of looks like an EAV store without being an actual one, with essentially random looking data mixed up with attribute and value fields. Is there any relationship between Col3 and Col4's content when they're ids or values, or are they as arbitrary as the question make them look?

Comment: `200-01-02` and `-2-1-1` are not valid dates. This results in not being able to `take minimum of timeBegin` if you cant ORDER the data because the data type is just a mystery. You will have to think in a different alternative or sanitise your data to become a real date. No other option is possible

Comment: @MostyMostacho Actually negative date imply the date in BC. Whereas positive date imply the date in AD..hope I am able to explain..and this inturn helps u to help me

Comment: @Denis Yes you are correct there is no relationship between col3 and col4 apart from them belonging to the same column.

Comment: "-200-3-## imply an uncertainty in time from (-200-3-31 to -200-3-01)" But -200-3-01 is before -200-3-31!

Comment: Also, what calendar are you using, in particular: what years are leap years?

Comment: Are you sure you need all of this? Do you already have lots of data that's been entered in this convoluted format?

Comment: Consider [**range types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html) (PostgreSQL 9.2+). In particular `tsrange` - or `tstzrange` to consider time zones.  
Then you can use [range type functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html) and [very efficient GiST indices out of the box](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns).

Comment: Should `timeBegin` be `200-01-01` instead of `200-01-02` in the second row of your example?

Comment: ...and why is `timeEnd` for `22##-##-##` `2200-12-31` rather than `2299-12-31`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is the best way, but here are a pair of Postgres functions that do the difficult bit of converting patterns to min and max dates:

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/295c7/1)</kbd>**

```
Create Function preprocessPattern(pat varchar(11), out cpat varchar(10), out neg boolean) as $$
declare
  y varchar(4);
  m varchar(2);
  d varchar(2);
  i int;
begin
  neg = false;
  if left(pat, 1) = '-' then
    neg = true;
    pat = right(pat, -1);
  end if;

  i = position('-' in pat);

  y = right('000' || left(pat, i - 1), 4);
  pat = right(pat, -i);
  i = position('-' in pat);
  m = right('0' || left(pat, i - 1), 2);
  pat = right(pat, -i);
  d = right('0' || pat, 2);
  cpat = y || '-' || m || '-' || d;
end;
$$ Language plpgsql;

Create Function dateFromFmt(fmt varchar(10), neg boolean) returns date as $$
begin
  if neg then
    return to_date(fmt || ' BC', 'yyyy-mm-dd BC');
  else
    return to_date(fmt, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  end if;
end;
$$ Language plpgsql;

Create Function minDateFromPattern(pat varchar(11)) returns date as $$
declare
    i int;
    neg boolean;
    n varchar(10);
begin
    select * into pat, neg from preprocessPattern(pat);
    i = position('#' in pat);
    if i = 0 then
      return dateFromFmt(pat, neg);
    else
      n = left(pat, i - 1) || right('0000-00-00', 0 - position('#' in pat) + 1);
      n = replace(n, '-00', '-01');
      return dateFromFmt(n, neg);
    end if;
end;
$$ Language plpgsql;


Create Function maxDateFromPattern(pat varchar(11)) returns date as $$
declare
    i int;
    y int;
    m int;
    d int;
    x varchar(10);
    neg boolean;
    res date;
begin
    select * into pat, neg from preprocessPattern(pat);
    i = position('#' in pat);
    if i = 0 then
        return dateFromFmt(pat, neg);
    elsif i = 1 then
        return date '9999-12-31';
        -- from here down, pick the next highest mask, convert to min date then subtract one day
    elsif i <= 6 then -- just add 1 to year
        if i = 6 then i = 5; end if; -- skip - char
        x = cast(cast(left(pat, i - 1) as int) + 1 as varchar) || right(pat, 0 - i + 1);
    else
      y = cast(left(pat, 4) as int);
      if i = 7 then
          m = cast(substr(pat, 6, 1) as int) + 1;
          if m = 2 then
              m = 0;
              y = y + 1;
          end if;
          x = left(to_char(y, 'FM0000'), 4) || '-' || to_char(m, 'FM0') || '#-##';
      elsif i = 9 then
          m = cast(substr(pat, 6, 2) as int) + 1;
          if m > 12 then
              m = 1;
              y = y + 1;
          end if;
          x = left(to_char(y, 'FM0000'), 4) || '-' || to_char(m, 'FM00') || '-##';
      elseif i = 10 then
          m = cast(substr(pat, 6, 2) as int);
          d = cast(substr(pat, 9, 1) as int) + 1;
          if (m = 2 and d = 3) or d = 4 then
              m = m + 1;
              d = 0;
              if m > 12 then
                  m = 1;
                  y = y + 1;
              end if;
          end if;
          x = left(to_char(y, 'FM0000'), 4) || '-' || to_char(m, 'FM00') || '-' || to_char(d, 'FM0') || '#';
      end if;
    end if;
    -- the original logic looks a little silly now as we're preprocessing twice
    res = minDateFromPattern(x) - interval '1 day';
    if neg then
      return dateFromFmt(to_char(res, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), neg);
    else
      return res;
    end if;
end;
$$ Language  plpgsql;
```

This has gone through enough iterations that it could use some refactoring

Comment: Sorry I did not get as to what is the 9999 problem that you are talking about..can you please explain it a bit

Comment: It expects all dates to fit in a 10 character string `yyyy-mm-dd`. For find the end date, it works out the day after and subtracts 1 from it. For year 9999, this could end up temporarily needing year 10000, which won't fit into 10 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The above functions does not seem to work for the year "200-##-##"..is there some way to rectify this

Comment: Although your code is excellent..still it does not work for dates e.g. "2013-12-12" which should be expanded into an uncertainty (2013-12-12,2013-12-12). Also it does not work for negative dates which stand for BC in postgres

Comment: @JannatArora more fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two parts in the question. One corresponds to aligning the table's data correctly. The other is processing the untold mess of a date format.

---

Assume two sql functions begin_time() and end_time() for now. I discuss them immediately below.

To align the data, left join the table twice with itself:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4,
       parse_begin_time(bt.col4) as timeBegin,
       parse_end_time(et.col4) as timeEnd
from yourtable t
left join yourtable as bt on begin_t.col2 = t.col1 and bt.col3 = 'timeBegin'
left join yourtable as et on end_t.col2 = t.col1 and et.col3 = 'timeEnd'
where t.col3 not in ('timeBegin', 'timeEnd');
```

If this yields multiple entries due to the presence of several entries, use aggregates:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4,
       min(parse_begin_time(bt.col4)) as timeBegin,
       max(parse_end_time(et.col4)) as timeEnd
from yourtable t
left join yourtable as bt on begin_t.col2 = t.col1 and bt.col3 = 'timeBegin'
left join yourtable as et on end_t.col2 = t.col1 and et.col3 = 'timeEnd'
where t.col3 not in ('timeBegin', 'timeEnd')
group by t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4;
```

Note: expect the above to not perform particularly well if you've a ton of data. Run them once in a create table as ... statement and get rid of the original schema, or create a materialized view for future use.

---

You then need to worry about pretty formatting the messy timeBegin and timeEnd fields, which I assume are stored in text fields. It's going to be something like this:

```
create or replace function parse_begin_time(text) returns date as $$
declare
  _input  text := $1;
  _output text;

  _bc     boolean := false;
  _y      text;
  _m      text;
  _d      text;

  _tmp    text;
  _i      int;
begin
  _input := trim(both from _input);

  -- PG is fine with '200-01-01 BC' as a date, but not with '-200-01-01'
  if left(_input, 1) = '-'
  then
    _bc    := true;
    _input := right(_input, -1);
  end if;

  -- Extract year, month and day
  _tmp := _input;
  _i   := position(_tmp for '-');
  _y   := substring(_tmp from 1 for i - 1);

  _tmp := substring(_tmp from i);
  _i   := position(_tmp for '-');
  _m   := substring(_tmp from 1 for i - 1);

  _tmp := substring(_tmp from i);
  _i   := position(_tmp for '-');
  _d   := substring(_tmp from 1 for i - 1);

  if _tmp <> '' or left(trim(left '0' from _y), 1) = 'X'
  then
    raise exception 'invalid date input: %', _input;
  end if;

  -- Prevent locale-specific text to date conversion issues with one or two digit years
  -- e.g. rewrite 1-2-3 as 0001-02-03.
  if length(_y) < 4
  then
    _y := lpad(_y, 4, '0');
  end if;

  if length(_m) < 2
  then
    _m := lpad(_m, 2, '0');
  end if;

  if length(_d) < 2
  then
    _d := lpad(_m, 2, '0');
  end if;

  -- Process year, month, day
  -- Add suitable logic here per your specs, using string and date functions
  -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html
  -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html
  -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html
  -- for end-of-months, use the built-in arithmetics, e.g.:
  -- _date := _date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'

  -- Build _output
  _output := _y || '-' || _m || '-' || _d;

  if _bc
    _output := _output || ' BC';
  end if;

  return _output::date;
end;
$$ language plpgsql strict stable;
```

The language could alternatively be plpython or plpythonu if you're more comfortable with it. I presume you know more about those two than I do, and certainly enough python to write the needed code. Laurence's code is another good starting point if you'd rather have things in plpgsql.

The `strict` statement tells Postgres to not bother calling the function on null input and to return null immediately. You probably don't want it for the end_time function.

Answer (score 0):

The method below uses a single SQL `SELECT` with `CASE` statements that apply the rules by post-processing a subquery. There are possible further tweaks that could be made but it gives the general idea. Apologies for the complexity - this started off fairly simple based on only the rules in the post but has been modified to handle the general case, which turned out to be pretty fiddly!

**Known limitation:** This method doesn't currently handle leap years very well and errs on the safe side by assuming the last day in February is always the 28th. This could be fixed but the leap year calculation isn't completely trivial so I've deliberatly left this bit out so as not to over-complicate.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
       CASE WHEN timeBegin IS NULL AND timeEnd IS NOT NULL
            THEN '01-01-01'
            WHEN timeBegin LIKE '-%' -- Handle negative (= BC) dates separately
            THEN CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-[0-1]#'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 2) || '9 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-1-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-31 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-2-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-28 BC' -- No leap year calculation
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-3-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-31 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-4-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-30 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-5-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-31 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-6-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-30 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-7-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-31 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-8-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-31 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-9-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-30 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-10-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-31 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-11-##'
                      THEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 4) || '-30 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-0#-##'
                      THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 7), '#', '9') || '-09-30 BC'
                      WHEN SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-12-##' OR SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2) LIKE '%-_#-##'
                      THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(timeBegin) - 7), '#', '9') || '-12-31 BC'
                      ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTRING(timeBegin, 2), '#', '9')
                 END
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(timeBegin, '-0#', '-01'), '-##', '-01'), '#', '0')
       END AS timeBegin,
       CASE WHEN timeEnd IS NULL AND timeBegin IS NOT NULL
            THEN '9999-12-12'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '-%' -- Handle negative (= BC) dates separately
            THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 2), '-0#', '-01'), '-##', '-01'), '#', '0') || ' BC'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-[0-1]#'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 1) || '9'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-1-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-1-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '31'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-2-2#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-2-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2)|| '28' -- No leap year calculation
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-3-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-3-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2)|| '31'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-4-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-4-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '30'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-5-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-5-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '31'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-6-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-6-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '30'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-7-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-7-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '31'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-8-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-8-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '31'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-9-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-9-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '30'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-10-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-10-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '31'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-11-3#' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-11-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 2) || '30'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-0#-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(timeEnd, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 5) || '09-30'
            WHEN timeEnd LIKE '%-1#-##' OR timeEnd LIKE '%-##-##'
            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(timeEnd, '#', '9'), 1, CHAR_LENGTH(timeEnd) - 5) || '12-31'
            ELSE REPLACE(timeEnd, '#', '9')
       END AS timeEnd
FROM
(SELECT t1.*,
        (SELECT Col4 FROM Tbl t2 WHERE (t1.Col1 = t2.Col2 OR t1.Col2 = t2.Col1)
                                   AND t2.Col3 = 'timeBegin') AS timeBegin,
        (SELECT Col4 FROM Tbl t2 WHERE (t1.Col1 = t2.Col2 OR t1.Col2 = t2.Col1)
                                   AND t2.Col3 = 'timeEnd') AS timeEnd
 FROM Tbl t1
 WHERE t1.Col3 NOT IN ('timeBegin', 'timeEnd')) subquery
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Col1, 3) AS INT)
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/70e2b/55), which shows it producing similar results to the posted example.

Comment: At first sight this would only work with the data from the example. This won't work, for instance, for a date such as `-200-4-##`

Comment: So it seems the rules in the post aren't the complete set. Here you have a different month, which makes me wonder if the bit at the start could also be different - for example would `666-09-##` be valid?

Comment: It seems the rules are just samples on how to handle the `#`, but I think you have to assume you can have anything else on the other fields.

Comment: Fair point. Have modified the answer for the general case but this turned out to be a lot more fiddly and hence more prone to bugs.